# cron management

Tags: cron

I have crontabs across multiple servers using different accounts. The scripts are separated such for a reason, different users for different services, etc. I did some searching for a tool to track what is running where in a central location, but didn't find anything. How are others keeping track of their crontabs? I'm writing some code now to fetch the crontabs from the servers and aggregate them in a central place, but was wondering if anyone has an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the crontab entries are for system functions, I suggest keeping them in `/etc/cron.d` in files by function, and mananging them there.  Alternatively, `/etc/crontab` also permits you to specify which user to run the entries as, so that's a good option also.

For keeping track you have two options.  Collect all of the crontabs to a central place, or distribute them all from a central place.  Either works; it is a question of where you want control to be.